# Update field using Apex

Tags: apex, class, custom-field, field-update, case-object

I am very new to Apex and found this site- hoping someone can help me out. We have a LOT of code-free automation on our cases and related objects, so we had to resort to Apex classes to do a few things, which we outsourced to a developer we no longer work with.

I would like to add a field update to the bottom of the apex code. Field is called "Quality Age" and should calculate number of days between Now and Created Date when a case status is changed to Completed (we had to use Apex to automate this status change). This is what I have so far, but keep getting errors. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, you should post code as text instead of an image, and if you're getting error messages you should include the full text of the error, varbatim. Also, if you're new to a part/feature in Salesforce, then Trailhead is going to be a better starting point. If you're entirely new to programming, then [Apex Basics for Admins](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex-basics-for-admins) is a good place to start. After that, the [Apex Basics & Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database) module is the next step.

Answer (score 2):

The method you're looking for is [`System.now()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_now) but you'll also need to loop over your collection (`List<Quality>`) to update each of the records:

```java
public class populateQualityAge {
    public Quality c;

    public static void populateField(List<Quality> ages) {
        for(Quality age : ages) {
            age.Quality_Age__c = System.now().date().daysBetween(age.CreatedDate.date());
        }

        update ages;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated to calculate number of days

Comment: Don't you need to do math on the `getTime()` values? I don't think `Datetime` math is supported as you have it here.

Comment: You are correct, I notice OP asked for "number of days" so I will update this answer with a more appropriate method.